# Revert UL LI tree in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have **`JSON`** with child.

```
const JSON_TREE = {
        name: "PARENT_3",
        id: "218",
        parent: {
            name: "PARENT_2",
            id: "217",
            parent: {
                name: "PARENT_1",
                id: "216"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can render this object from `component`

```
export default class Tree extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let data = this.props.data;
        return (
            <ul>
                {data.id}: {data.name}
                <li>
                    {data.parent !== undefined && <Tree data={data.parent}/>}
                </li>
            </ul>

        )
    }
}
```

And get **next render**:

```
    218: PARENT_3
        217: PARENT_2
            216: PARENT_1
```

But I **expect render**:

```
   216: PARENT_1
       217: PARENT_2
           218: PARENT_3
```

I think I can reorder `JSON` object before render, but it not seem like good idea.
How I can do this?

Comment: That's not a very good structure to work with unfortunately. Ideally, your root element should be at the top, and the children should come below. "I think I can reorder JSON object before render"...unfortunately, that's ultimately how you're going to have to solve this issue most likely.

Comment: By any chance are you working with Graphql?

Comment: @MSoheb probably it's my chance)

Answer (score 0):

For such a task, in meaning of better performance i would use styling. Flex boxes `flex-direction: column-reverse;`
But if you wish to reverse the object `.reverse();`

Comment: You can't just `.reverse()` a nested object like that.

Answer (score 0):

Like @FrankerZ said you will neeed to use css for such a task to ensure performance otherwise it will get messy real fast. Column-reverse with flex is your best bet. Create a sandbox for me to apply the css solution